# Proof of assets for Canada visitor visa

Tags: canada, proof-provenance-of-funds

I am a student from India and I am applying for Canada visitor visa. One of the requirements state **Proof of assets**. Since I am a student, I have no personal asset. I live in our parental house which belongs to my grandparents and there is a joint property of my mother and my aunt.

How can I show proof of assets in this case? And what else can come under proof of assets?

Comment: If you have no assets, say so on the application. They will not ask you to prove that you have no assets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While you do not have to give proof of assets, you do have to provide evidence that you have enough money for proposed travels to Canada.

> You must meet some [basic requirements to travel to Canada](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/apply-who.asp?lnktrk=visa_less_six_months). You must:
>
> - have a valid travel document, like a passport
> - be in good health
> - have no criminal or immigration-related convictions
> - convince an immigration officer that you have ties—such as a job, home, financial assets or family—that will take you back to your home country
> - convince an immigration officer that you will leave Canada at the end of your visit
> - have enough money for your stay.
>
> The amount of money you will need depends on how long you will stay and if you will stay in a hotel, or with friends or relatives.
>
> [Applying for Visitor Visa (Temporary Resident Visa – IMM 5256)](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/information/applications/guides/5256ETOC.asp#overview)